# How can I avoid the message Infinity::indet?

Tags: warning-messages, series-expansion, trigonometry

I have an impulse train of frequency `R`:

```
1/(R + 1) + (Sum[Cos[(2 k π x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}])/(R + 1)
```

For `x = 0`, the function is equal to `1` regardless of the value of `R`. This is because

```
Cos[(2 k π x)/(R + 1)] /. x -> 0 == Cos[0] == 1
```

and

```
1/(R + 1) + (Sum[1, {k, R}])/(R + 1) == 1/(R + 1) + R/(R + 1) == 
  (R + 1)/(R + 1) == 1
```

Mathematica disagrees with me. The command

```
Evaluate[1/(R + 1) + (Sum[Cos[(2 k π x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}])/(R + 1) /. x -> 0]
```

produces the message

> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.`

This is clearly wrong. Can anyone suggest how I work around it?

Comment: It's an indeterminate form (and this is exactly what the substitution indicates). So one should take a limit: `In[8]:= Limit[
 1/(R + 1) + (Sum[Cos[(2 k \[Pi] x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}])/(R + 1), x -> 0]

Out[8]= 1`

Comment: Will the `Limit` suggestion work with plots and the like?

Comment: I should rephrase that. *How* do I make this work with `Plot`? I want to graph the product of this function and another function, but without the discontinuities.

Comment: Can you give me a half hour? The doorbell just rang...

Comment: OK, so I am multiplying the function above by `(2 x)/(X^2+1)^2`. At `x=0`, this should give `0`, since that is the value of the second function at `x=0`. However, Mathematica displays a discontinuity. I can't upload a picture in comments, but hopefully you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide the full example that gives you the headaches. A simple plot works. It's not clear what is the capital `X`, and what value for the `R` you are substituting, and what kind of Plot you do.

Comment: OK, sorry it wasn't clear. The full function I want to plot is: `((2 x)/(X^2+1)^2)((1/(R+1)+(Sum[Cos[(2 k \[Pi] x)/(R+1)],{k,R}])/(R+1)))`. This *should* produce `(0)(1)=0` at `x=0`. (The value of `R` is irrelevant since it cancels.) But Mathematica returns a discontinuity at `x=0`. I can't use `Limit` because that only applies to a specific value of `x`. I want the whole *curve*, without the incorrect indeterminate result at `x=0`.

Comment: (And apologies for the capital `X` - an error.)

Comment: Can you please just update the question, so that it shows an expression I can evaluate and see the error? It is much easier to help you this way. Also, it is still unclear *what* problem you are solving. The function can be plotted just fine. `f[R_, x_] = ((2 x)/(x^2 + 1)^2) ((1/(R + 1) + (Sum[ Cos[(2 k \[Pi] x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}])/(R + 1))); Plot[f[20, x], {x, -2, 2}]`. The repairable discontinuity at $x/(R+1)\in\mathbb{Z}$ seems like an artifact of the method, and `Plot` can deal with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the [`Sin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html) and [`Csc`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Csc.html) functions in terms of the [`Sinc`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sinc.html) function.

```
Clear[f]

f[x_, R_] = ((2 x/(x^2 + 1)^2) ((1/(R + 1) + (Sum[
            Cos[(2 k π x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}])/(R + 1))) // 
     FullSimplify) /. {Sin[z_] :> z*Sinc[z], Csc[z_] :> 1/(z*Sinc[z])} // 
  Simplify

(* (x + ((1 + 2 R) x Sinc[(π (1 + 2 R) x)/(1 + R)])/
 Sinc[(π x)/(1 + R)])/((1 + R) (1 + x^2)^2) *)

f[0, R]

(* 0 *)

Plot3D[f[x, R], {x, -3, 3}, {R, 0, 5},
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 6]
```

[image]

Expanding the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)

```
Plot3D[f[x, R], {x, -3, 3}, {R, 0, 5},
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 6,
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your function in Piecewise form.

```
Limit[1/(R + 1) + Sum[Cos[(2*k*Pi*x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}]/(R + 1), x -> 0]
(*1*)

fn1 = Piecewise[{{1, x == 0}}, 
   1/(R + 1) + (Sum[Cos[(2 k \[Pi] x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}])/(R + 1)] // Simplify;

fn2 = (2 x)/(x^2 + 1)^2;

fn[x_, R_] = fn1 fn2;
```

You can then plot `fn[x,R]` with no indeterminant problems.