# Why is this function indeterminate?

Tags: warning-messages, series-expansion, trigonometry

Consider an impulse train

```
1/(R + 1) + (Sum[Cos[(2 k π x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}])/(R + 1)
```

For `x=0` it's clear that this function should return `1`, because `Cos[0]==1`, which gives `1/(R+1)+R/(R+1)==1`.

However, if I evaluate

```
1/(R + 1) + (Sum[Cos[(2 k π x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}])/(R + 1)/. x -> 0
```

I get an indeterminate result. (And this still happens if I assign a specific value to `R`.)

I'd like to know the reason. On a different thread, people have very helpfully given me a workaround using `Sinc`. But I just want to figure out the cause of the issue. What's the logic behind the error?

Comment: How is this different from [this previous question of yours](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/178728/34893)?

Comment: The previous question (as noted) was how to solve the issue. This question is, why does the issue arise?

Comment: The answers to the other question told you why. `Sin[x]/x` for `x=0` only exists in the limit. `Sinc[x]` avoids the issue by defining the function at `x=0` to equal the limit. Or make the replacement prior to evaluating the `Sum`: `1/(R + 1) + (Sum[Cos[(2 k \[Pi] x)/(R + 1)] /. x -> 0, {k, R}])/(R + 
     1) // Simplify`

Comment: I think you're assuming I'm smarter than I am! I understand about `Sin[x]/x`, but that's not the point. This is a `Cos` function. There is no division by `x` involved. And, again, I'm not after a fix, I'm trying to figure out the *why*.

Comment: A slightly more interesting question is, "Why doesn't `Sum[x^2/(1 + x^2)^n, {n, 1, Infinity}] /. x -> 0` return zero?" I suppose both it and yours could be comprised under the heading "Algebraic expressions tend to be only generically valid" (generic meaning they are possibly invalid on a set that is much smaller than the domain, such as a finite number of exceptions or a set of one dimension less). In your case, you have an expression that contains something like `Sin[(1+2R) u] Csc[u]`, which is undefined but has limit at `u == 0` as @Bob says. My unfortunate example has a discontinuity.

Comment: OK, I'm getting closer to understanding. But why is it true that I have an expression "that contains something like `Sin[(1+2R) u] Csc[u]`"? Because actually, it doesn't. I assume you mean that there are different ways of thinking about the expression, and only one of them returns my desired result...?

Comment: Evaluate the expression `1/(R + 1) + (Sum[Cos[(2 k \[Pi] x)/(R + 1)], {k, R}])/(R + 1)` and you will see that Mma can express the sum in a closed-form prior to the replacement rule. That is why I mentioned that if you did the replacement prior to the summation, the issue would not arise.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward Oops, I let a `Simplify` slip in and got this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fWfu8.png -- Before simplification, you have two terms with `Csc[(\[Pi] x)/(1 + R)]` in the result of `Sum[..]`, each of which is undefined at `x == 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see exactly where and why the indeterminate arises if you look through the output of this

```
Trace[1/(R+1) + (Sum[Cos[(2 k Pi x)/(R+1)], {k, R}])/(R+1) /. x->0]
```

The output of that may seem confusing if you haven't looked at this before, but what it does is show you step by step the evaluation process and what the result was for each tiny step.

For example, the very first step shows `{R+1,1+R}` which shows it is trying to determine the value of your very first `(R+1)` and it concludes that is `1+R` because Mathematica displays polynomials in a different order.

You can look at the step by step process of the evaluation. After some steps you can see that it thinks it needs to turn one of your `Cos` into `Csc`. Then further on you can see it finds this is `Csc[0]` and that is where your indeterminate or `ComplexInfinity` comes from.

Now we come to a little more guesswork. From your previous question I am tending to think that you believe that `0*anything==0`, no matter what `anything` is, but that is just me guessing what you are thinking. Does this correctly represent your thinking? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Mathematica doesn't think `0*anything==0` in some cases. You can see that Mathematica believes `0*3==0` and `0*a==0`, even when mathematica does not yet know what the value of `a` is, but it does not think that`0*Infinity==0`.

Might this explain your questioning Mathematica's result?

From the output of `Trace` you might be able to try to guess parts of the process and the rules that Mathematica is using to evaluate expressions like yours.

Comment: It's the turning `Cos` into `Csc` that is messing with me. I do realise that `0*anything==0` is only true when `anything` is both clearly defined and `!=0`. You've all been really helpful. I appreciate it. I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: The `Csc` factor arises from an identity for the sum of cosines, not from `Cos` turning into `Csc` per se.