# How to solve these ODEs using NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I have six odes and I cannot use DSolve. So I tried NDSolve. But it says there may be some errors.The code is such like this:

```
I1 = 2; I2 = 3; I3 = 4;
NDSolve[{I1*ω1'[t] + (I3 - I2)*ω2[t]*ω3[t] == 0, 
I2*ω2'[t] + (I1 - I3)*ω1[t]*ω3[t] == 0, 
I3*ω3'[t] + (I2 - I1)*ω2[t]*ω1[t] == 0, 
ω1[t] == φ'[t]*Sin[θ[t]]*Sin[ψ[t]] + θ'[t]*Cos[ψ[t]], 
ω2[t] == φ'[t]*Sin[θ[t]]*Cos[ψ[t]] - θ'[t]*Sin[ψ[t]], 
ω3[t] == φ'[t]*Cos[θ[t]] + ψ'[t], 
ω1[0] == 2, ω2[0] == 3, ω3[0] == 4, ψ[0] == 0, φ[0] == 0, θ[0] == Pi/6}, 
{ω1, ω2, ω3, ψ, φ, θ}, {t, 0, 120}]
```

I want to know how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 4):

The computation fails at `t = 0` because `Sin[ψ[t]]` vanishes there.  However, this problem can be circumvented by eliminating `Sin[ψ[t]]` as follows.  Define for convenience,

```
eq1 = ω1[t] - (φ'[t]*Sin[θ[t]]*Sin[ψ[t]] + θ'[t]*Cos[ψ[t]]);
eq2 = ω2[t] - (φ'[t]*Sin[θ[t]]*Cos[ψ[t]] - θ'[t]*Sin[ψ[t]]};
```

and construct the linear combinations,

```
eq1n = Simplify[eq1 Sin[ψ[t]] + eq2 Cos[ψ[t]]]
eq2n = Simplify[eq1 Cos[ψ[t]] - eq2 Sin[ψ[t]]]
(* Sin[ψ[t]] ω1[t] + Cos[ψ[t]] ω2[t] - Sin[θ[t]] φ'[t] *)
(* Cos[ψ[t]] ω1[t] - Sin[ψ[t]] ω2[t] - φ'[t] *)
```

(If this were not possible, the equations could not be solved, even in principle.)

Now replace `eq1, eq2` by `eq1n, eq2n`.

```
I1 = 2; I2 = 3; I3 = 4;
s = NDSolveValue[{I1*ω1'[t] + (I3 - I2)*ω2[t]*ω3[t] == 0, 
    I2*ω2'[t] + (I1 - I3)*ω1[t]*ω3[t] == 0, 
    I3*ω3'[t] + (I2 - I1)*ω2[t]*ω1[t] == 0, 
    eq1n == 0, eq2n == 0, 
    ω3[t] == φ'[t]*Cos[θ[t]] + ψ'[t], 
    ω1[0] == 2, ω2[0] == 3, ω3[0] == 4, ψ[0] == 0, φ[0] == 0, θ[0] == Pi/6}, 
    {ω1[t], ω2[t], ω3[t], ψ[t], φ[t], θ[t]}, {t, 0, 120}];
Plot[Evaluate@s[[1 ;; 3]], {t, 0, 120}, ImageSize -> Large]
Plot[Evaluate@s[[4 ;; 6]], {t, 0, 120}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

[image]

Incidentally, the original equations also can be solved by modifying slightly the initial condition `ψ[0] == 0` to `ψ[0] == 10^-6`.

And still another approach is to use the option,

```
Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
```

All give the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect, the error message indicates that we are have `1/0` and I think this is because of `Sin[]` so I adopted the idea from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178728/how-can-i-avoid-the-message-infinityindet) to change it in to `Sinc`.

> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression
>   ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered.

```
I1 = 2; I2 = 3; I3 = 4;

Eq1 = I1*ω1'[t] + (I3 - I2)*ω2[t]*ω3[t] == 0;

Eq2 = I2*ω2'[t] + (I1 - I3)*ω1[t]*ω3[t] == 0;

Eq3 = I3*ω3'[t] + (I2 - I1)*ω2[t]*ω1[t] == 0;

Eq4 = ω1[t] == (φ'[t]*Sin[θ[t]]*Sin[ψ[t]] + θ'[t]*Cos[ψ[t]] ) /. {Sin[z_] :> 
    z*Sinc[z], Csc[z_] :> 1/(z*Sinc[z])};

Eq5 = ω2[t] == (φ'[t]*Sin[θ[t]]*Cos[ψ[t]] - θ'[t]*Sin[ψ[t]]) /. {Sin[z_] :> 
    z*Sinc[z], Csc[z_] :> 1/(z*Sinc[z])};

Eq6 = ω3[t] == φ'[t]*Cos[θ[t]] + ψ'[t];

sol = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4, Eq5, Eq6, ω1[0] == 2, ω2[0] == 3, ω3[0] == 
    4, ψ[0] == 0, φ[0] == 0, θ[0] == Pi/6}, {ω1, ω2, ω3, ψ, φ, θ}, {t, 0, 120}];

Plot[Evaluate[{ω1[t], ω2[t], ω3[t], ψ[t], φ[t], θ[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 120}, PlotRange -> All]
```