# Analytic solution of a system of six ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of six ODEs for six function. I want to get the analytic solution of the system. I have used `DSolve`, but it can not solve it.

The code is:

```
DSolve[
  {I1*ω1'[t] + (I3 - I2)*ω2[t]*ω3[t] == 0, 
   I2*ω2'[t] + (I1 - I3)*ω1[t]*ω3[t] == 0, 
   I3*ω3'[t] + (I2 - I1)*ω2[t]*ω1[t] == 0, 
   ω1[t] == φ'[t]*Sin[θ[t]]*Sin[ψ[t]] + θ'[t]*Cos[ψ[t]], 
   ω2t] == φ'[t]*Sin[θ[t]]*Cos[ψ[t]] - θ'[t]*Sin[ψ[t]], 
   ω3[t] == φ'[t]*Cos[θ[t]] + ψ'[t], 
   ω1[0] == 2, ω2[0] == 3, ω3[0] == 4, ψ[0] == 0, φ[0] == 0, θ[0] == Pi/6}, 
  {ω1, ω2, ω3, ψ, φ, θ}, t]
```

I want to know if there is some method I can use to get a solution.

Also, I have tried `NDSolve, but there may be some errors. I would prefer to get an analytic solution.

Comment: what's the I1,I2,I3 !???

Comment: Please clarify your functions and Initial conditions mathematically clearly.
you can upload a pic of the problem as well if available, so we can help!

Comment: check this they gave you a solutions!
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193404/how-to-solve-these-odes-using-ndsolve

Comment: Note that this version of the question is asking for an analytical solution, rather than a numerical one, so it's not an exact duplicate.  That said, these equations are the well-known [Euler equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)) for rigid-body dynamics, and I'd be *very* surprised if an analytical solution existed for them.  You might try asking over on [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com) whether an analytic solution is known to exist, but my guess would be that such a solution only exists under limited conditions.